# Weird x-values when plotting live time series in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to plot a time series for the last 2 hours, just a bunch of points with a timestamp and a value. e.g. `{time: 1234234553, value: 34}`

When a new point arrives I push it onto the end of a list `data`

and replot everything in the list:

```
function redraw() 
{
    var TS = new Date().getTime(); // current time stamp
    var T = (60*60*2*1000); // last two hours

    chart.selectAll("rect")
     .data(data)
   .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d, i)   { return x(d.time - TS + T); })
     .attr("y", function(d)      { return H - y(d.value); })
     .attr("width", function(d)  { return 2; })
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); });
}
```

But unforunately the point appears on the left of the plot instead of the right and when I look at the source in Firebug for the SVG the entry has a weird x value:

```
<rect x="function (){}" y="354.9553019925952" width="2" height="45.044698007404804"/>
```

Can anyone help? Do I need to remove all the plotted data and re-plot it?

Appendix:

In case you need to see x() and y()

```
var T = (60*60*2*1000); // 1 hurs

var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, T])
        .range([0, W]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }), 10])
        .range([0, H]);
```

Comment: Pardon any obvious suggestions, but (1) do you get what you expect with `console.log(x(/*new value*/ - TS + T))` and (2) do you get what you expect with `console.log(/*new value*/ - TS + T)` when those are stuck in after you append the new data point to `data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to step-by-step tutorial how to make your plot.

**[Part I](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html)**, **[Part II](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html)** (I guess you read it)

I think that new rect can go on the left only if you give wrong "x" position.

This `return x(d.time - TS + T);` looks fine.
So I think, problem somewhere in `d.time` & `TS`.

Are you shure that you have timestamps with the same TZ? Difference in 2hr will give such effect. Or may be the "New Point" is not very recent.